# couldn't open database

Tags: c#, .net, database, sqlite

i have my c# application in c:\program files\app\ folder
i am using sqllite database

my code working perfectly while logging via windows administrative user, if i change window user account to limited, i couldn't open my database

```
public  void OpenDB()
{
 SQConnectionString = "Data Source=" + DBPath +";Pooling=true;FailIfMissing=false";
 con = new SQLiteConnection();
 con.ConnectionString = SQConnectionString;
 con.Open();
}
```

Comment: Check the permissions on the database file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Program Files* directory is definitely not the right place to put data... On Windows Vista and Seven, this directory can't be written to unless the application is running as administrator. You should put the database in *ProgramData* or the user's data directory. You can obtain these directories with the `Environment.GetFolderPath` method :

```
string userAppData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
// On Vista and Seven, this is C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming
// On XP, this is C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Application Data

string commonAppData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
// On Vista and Seven, this is C:\ProgramData
// On XP, this is C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the non-admin user have `write` privileges on the directory where you installed SQLite?  Because this might happen if you are using the journal file.

Answer (score 0):

That's because non-admin users don't have write access to the `program files` folder